# aws sdk copyObject from one bucket to another bucket

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, coffeescript, aws-sdk

How do I copy a Object from one bucket to another? I've tried following approach.

```
s3.listObjects optsList, Meteor.bindEnvironment (err, result)->
            if err?
                throw err
            else
                optsCopy =
                    Bucket: _cloud.bucket
                    CopySource: _cloud.bucket + '/' + prfx + doc.filename
                    Key: _cloudMediaData.bucket + '/' + _cloudMediaData.upload_prefix + uploadPrfx + doc.filename
                if result.Body? and result.Body.ListBucketResult? and result.Body.ListBucketResult.Contents?
                    for file in _.flatten [result.Body.ListBucketResult.Contents]
                        s3.copyObject optsCopy, Meteor.bindEnvironment (err, data)->
                            if err?
                                throw err
                            else
                                console.log 'Copied: ' + optsCopy.Key
```

But with this code I get following Error.

```
Exception in callback of async function: { Code: 'AwsSumCheck', Message: 'Provide a SourceBucket' }
```

the Bucket in the optsCopy is `sourceBucket`

the CopySource is `sourceBucket/user_uploads/*userID*/A_100_test.gif`

the Key is `destinationBucket/workdata/A_/A_100/A_100_test.gif`

The listObjects is working fine, and I will get the files as the result.

Comment: set bucket option to your destination bucket name and key should be without a bucket like /workdata/A_/A_100/A_100_test.gif and try.:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#copyObject-property

Comment: @vishalpatil thanks for the suggestion, but it seems not to work. I will get the same Error.